# Generic Constraint for Non Nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, interface

I have the following class:

```
public class KeyDTO<T>
{
     public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good, but I want the type parameter **T** to be a non-nullable type.
I've read somewhere that this may be feasible:

```
public class KeyDTO<T> where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>
{
     public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

But, If i change `public T Id` to `public T? Id`, I get a compilation error telling me that `T` must be non-nullable.

How can I specify that a generic type parameter must be non-nullable?

## Edit

I want to accomplish this because I want to annotate my `Id` property with the `[Required]` attribute as follows:

```
public class KeyDTO<T> {
    [Required]
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

What `[Required]` does is validate the model so `T` cannot be null.

However, if I have `KeyDTO<int>`, `Id` will be initialized to `0`, bypassing my `[Required]` attribute

Answer (score 101, accepted):

From C# 8.0 you can now use the `where T : notnull` generic constraint to specificy `T` is a non-nullable type.

Comment: "Generic declarations that include the notnull constraint can be used in a nullable oblivious context, but compiler does not enforce the constraint." So if you aren't compiling with `nullable enable` it won't do anything.

Comment: nullable reference types are finally enabled in .NET 6 project templates by default

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 3.1 with "Nullable: enable" on project build config. This worked for me

Answer (score 43):

Applying `where T : struct` applies a generic constraint that `T` be a non-nullable value type.  Since there are no non-nullable reference types, this has the exact same semantics as simply "all non-nullable types".  Nullable value types (i.e. `Nullable<T>`) do not satisfy the `struct` generic constraint.

Comment: Good explanation (+1). But I have a question: din't Nullable<T> requires `where T : struct`. Isn't a problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Since Nullable is a value type, would inherit from struct. Correct? If so, how instructing `where T : struct` exclude the non-nullable types? Does this make sense? I am sorry but I can't get it.

Comment: @Christos It doesn't apply to that constraint because that's what the C# language specs say should happen.  Note there is no `struct` type.  It is not something that is inherited from.  It is a concept; some types satisfy it, and some don't.  It's that simple.

Comment: Please notice the date on this answer, it was true when it was written.  In 2019 c# 8.0 adds non-nullable reference types to C#.

Comment: But what if `TId` was `Guid`?  That isn't a valid struct value type right?