# Receiving error about nullable type parameter even when parameter has notnull constraint

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a generic interface `IDataAdapter<T>`; implementors of the interface should be able to read POCOs with `Guid` IDs from a data source. `IDataAdapter<T>` has a method `Read(Guid id)` which I want to return a `T?`, where null indicates that no matches were found in the data source. However, even with a constraint `T : notnull` on `IDataAdapter<T>`, attempting to define this method gives the error `CS8627: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.` Why am I still getting this error, even with `T` constrained to `notnull`?

Code (should be in a C# 8 environment with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`):

```
interface IDataAdapter<T> where T : notnull
{
    T? Read (Guid id); // error CS8627
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Constraint for Non Nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489229/generic-constraint-for-non-nullable-types)

Comment: What version do yo used? net core 3.0 or net standard 2.1?

Comment: @keysl core 3.0.

Comment: @Manvinder Singh I don't think that's a duplicate; that question/answer predates c#8's nullable reference types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this issue is very similar to what is happening in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593923/nullable-reference-types-with-generic-return-type/54594285#54594285).

Note that a `T? where T : class` and a `T? where T : struct` are represented very differently in the CLR. The former is just the CLR type `T`. **There are not separate types in the CLR to differentiate between `T` and `T?`.** `T?` in C# just adds extra compile time checking by the C# compiler. On the other hand, The latter is represented by the CLR type `Nullable<T>`.

So let's consider your method:

```
T? Read (Guid id);
```

How should this be represented in the CLR? What is the return type? The compiler don't know whether `T` is a reference type or a value type, so the compiler cannot decide whether the method signature should be:

```
T Read (Guid id);
```

or:

```
Nullable<T> Read (Guid id);
```

Answer (score 3):

The same error is raised if you don't use the `notnull` constraint. You need to specify what that type is with a `class` or `struct` constraint. You don't need to specify `notnull` as structs were always nullable and, with nullable ref types enabled, so are classes.

Just add `where T:class` or `where T:struct`.

**Reference Types**

If you add the `class` constraint, eg:

```
#nullable enable

interface IDataAdapter<T>       
    where T:class
{
    T? Read (Guid id); // error CS8627
    
    void Something(T input);
}

class StringAdapter:IDataAdapter<string>
{
    public string Read(Guid id)=>id.ToString();
    
    public void Something(string input){}
}
```

The following call will generate a warning:

```
var adp=new StringAdapter();
string? x=null;
adp.Something(x);  //CS8604: Possible null reference argument ....
```

**Value Types**

Using `struct` to create an `IntAdapter` on the other hand results in a compilation error if the argument is nullable :

```
interface IDataAdapter<T>       
    where T:struct
{
    T? Read (Guid id); // error CS8627
    
    void Something(T input);
}


class IntAdapter:IDataAdapter<int>
{
    public int? Read(Guid id)=>id.ToString().Length;
    
    public void Something(int input){}
}

void Main()
{
    
    var adp=new IntAdapter();
    int? x=null;
    adp.Something(x);  //CS1503: Cannot convert from int? to int
}
```

That's because the compile generated methods that expect an `int?` instead of an `int`.

**Explanation**

The reason is that the compiler has to generate very different code in each case. For a class, it doesn't have to do anything special. For a struct, it has to generate a Nullable< T>.

This is explained in the `The issue with T?` section in [Try out Nullable Reference Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) :

> This distinction between nullable value types and nullable reference types comes up in a pattern such as this:
>
> `void M<T>(T? t) where T: notnull`
>
> This would mean that the parameter is the nullable version of T, and T is constrained to be notnull. If T were a string, then the actual signature of M would be M([NullableAttribute] T t), but if T were an int, then M would be M(Nullable t). These two signatures are fundamentally different, and this difference is not reconcilable.
>
> Because of this issue between the concrete representations of nullable reference types and nullable value types, any use of T? must also require you to constrain the T to be either class or struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Nullable Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8)'s documentation you can see that it requires to be a `struct`:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

I believe you will need to constraint T to be a `struct`:

```
interface IA<T> where T : struct
{
    T? Read(Guid id);
    // Or Nullable<T> Read(Guid id);
}


class A : IA<int>
{
    public int? Read(Guid id) { Console.WriteLine("A"); return 0; }
}
```

---

BTW. Could you give us an example of what types you want to use this class with?

Why not just use `where T: class` and return `T` (or even not have a constraint at all)?

```
interface IA<T> where T : class
{
    T Read(Guid id);
}
```