# Best way to avoid warnings for generics with nullable types/fields?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Consider the following contrived class:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public void SetItem(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T GetItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }

    T _item; // warning CS8618: Non-nullable field '_item' is uninitialized.
}            // Consider declaring the field as nullable.
```

Assume that it must work with the following code:

```
var test1 = new Test<int>();
test1.SetItem(1);
Console.WriteLine(test1.GetItem());

var test2 = new Test<string>();
test2.SetItem("One");
Console.WriteLine(test2.GetItem());
```

Further assume that `nullable` is enabled when compiling.

This implementation yields a compiler warning (which turns into an error if, like us, you have "warnings as errors" enabled):

> warning CS8618: Non-nullable field '_item' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the field as nullable.

My question is simple:

**What is the best way to avoid this warning?**

Things I have tried:

1) Declaring _item as nullable:

```
T? _item; // Error: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type
```

2) Declaring the class as:

```
public sealed class Test<T> where T: struct
```

This avoids the warning, but now the line `var test2 = new Test<string>();` will not compile

3) Declaring the class as:

```
public sealed class Test<T> where T: class
...
T? _item;
```

This also avoids the warning, but now the line `var test1 = new Test<int>();` will not compile.

So what I have at the moment is this:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public void SetItem(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T GetItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }

    #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
    T _item;
    #pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
}
```

Is this really the best option I have?

Note: I've seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489229/generic-constraint-for-non-nullable-types), but it doesn't answer my question since the answer says to use `where T : struct`, which - as noted above - does not solve the issue.

---

[Edited after receiving the correct answer]

So it turns out that for a generic type, there is no way of using nullable to express the case that "if T is a nullable type, then it can be null".

However, Resharper DOES allow you do to this, so I'm using a combination of both.

The class looks like this when using Resharper support as well as nullable:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public void SetItem([CanBeNull] T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    [CanBeNull] public T GetItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }

    [CanBeNull] T _item = default!;
}
```

Now when I write code like this:

```
var test = new Test<string>();
Console.WriteLine(test.GetItem().Length); // Warning: Possible null reference exception.
```

Resharper warns me about `test.GetItem()` possibly returning a null - even though the compiler doesn't.

(It's a shame that the C# compiler gives me no way to do this, but at least we have Resharper!)

---

[Edit after further consideration]

If I just use the class like this:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public void SetItem(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T GetItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }

    T _item = default!;
}
```

Then it becomes the responsibility of the instantiating code to supply the correct nullable type of T if needed, like so:

```
var test = new Test<string?>();
```

And now the compiler itself will warn you if you attempt to dereference a possibly-null reference:

```
var test = new Test<string?>(); // Note "string?"
Console.WriteLine(test.GetItem().Length); // Warning about test.GetItem() possibly null.
```

This is definitely preferable to using Resharper annotations like I did in my second edit, since that is actually wrong because it means that you can't say that the values are NOT null.

---

[Hopefully final clarifying edit]

The actual class does not allow `_item` to be accessed unless it was explicitly set, so it's more like this:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public void SetItem(T item)
    {
        _wasSet = true;
        _item = item;
    }

    public T GetItem()
    {
        if (!_wasSet)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No item set.");

        return _item;
    }

    T _item = default!;

    bool _wasSet;
}
```

Because of the way the real class is used, the item to be set is not available at the time that the object is instantiated, so it's not possible to set the default in the constructor.

(The real class is something someone has written to provide a queue where you can access the first AND the second items in the queue without dequeueing them, and `_item` is in fact a separate value used for the front of the queue, with the remainder of the queue being stored in a `Queue<T>`. That's not the way I'd have done it, really, but that's what I'm working with...)

Comment: What would you expect to happen if someone called `var test = new Test<string>(); string x = test.GetItem();`? Basically your code is lying about the nullability - so it makes sense that there's a warning. It would be best if you could accept the item in your constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet In that case, I'd expect it to return null (which of course it does). The problem is just that it's not possible to express the case that "if type T is a reference type, then it could be null". (The class I showed is quite contrived - the real code is more complex and I'm trying to convert it to nullable without having to make too many changes.)

Comment: In my experience, using nullability along with generics is going to be a major headache, precisely because of the problems you've seen in the code. There doesn't seem to be any good way to specify non-nullability for T members of a generic type and still support both structs and classes. Your best option is to design the class to allow null, which means you're going to have to force the compiler to accept your code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think my most recent edit seems to solve the issue completely. I avoid the warning, but the compiler still warns me if the type is nullable when I dereference it. This is also how `List<T>` works with, for example, `List<string?>`

Comment: Well, what if you do: `var x = new Test<string>(); var y = x.GetItem().Length;`? That compiles, no warnings (because `T` is not `T?` so there is a promise here you're not getting `null`, but you are because of `default!`). Basically, `GetItem()` returns `T`, not `T?`, so it shouldn't return `null`, but the default value is `default!`, which is basically "null, don't complain!".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But if the string is nullable, it should be `var x = new Test<string?>();`, and then you DO get the warning. It's exactly the same as how `List<T>` works - I should have realised that ages ago, but my train of thought went down the wrong track... ;)

Comment: The difference is that `List<T>` doesn't add elements to the list that it selects itself, but in your class you have picked the default value yourself, which is `null` for reference types. However, if you specify a non-nullable reference type for `T`, the GetItem method will still return `null`, but it shouldn't, at least if you want the compiler to correctly warn you about problematic cases.

Comment: If you instead only allow the value of the item to get its default using a constructor parameter, you put the responsibility on the calling code to give the right default, and then there should at least not be any surprises.

Comment: If you want your type to be generic, you *should* support both `new Test<string>().GetItem().Length` and `new Test<string?>().GetItem().Length` but I don't think you can and still get the nullable warnings in *all* the right places.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In the actual class, the item that is defaulted can only be validly returned if it was set by calling `SetItem()` - otherwise a specific exception is thrown. So in that case, the default value for `_item` is *never* used - but I wanted to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I can only comment on the code you've posted, not the code you didn't post. My comment is still valid for the code in your question, but it shouldn't be valid for your actual implementation then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a possible option, you use combination of [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) literal and [`null-forgiving`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) operator, like

```
private T _item = default!;
```

Comment: That works! I should have thought of that. (I'll mark as the answer when  I can.)

Comment: You're converting existing code to nullable by circumventing the feature. Looks like a bad idea. If there is an existing bug that uses the null value you're still left with it.

Comment: @Dialecticus It's ok in this instance because the class already can return nulls, so the code is already handling it. The class is trying to express the fact that "if T is nullable, then it could have a null value". The problem is that with generics and nullable, there is actually no way to express that fact if the type parameter could be a reference OR a value type.

Comment: Fortunately, if you're using Resharper there IS a way to express this, so I'm using that in addition to using nullable. I'll add that to my question to clarify.